# Thymeleaf, how to delcare default values for variables?

Tags: thymeleaf

For example,
`sortDir` field is passed to model, but if I forget it, I want to use `asc` as default one.

This does not work as it shows div only when `sortDir==null`.

```
<div class="wrapper"
 th:if="${sortDir == null}" th:with="sortDir=${'asc'}">
// Main content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove your conditional on the div and try to decide on the value with an inline expression as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper" 
  th:with="sortDir=${sortDir != null} ? sortDir : 'asc'">
// Main content
</div>
```

Another way to achieve this is by setting the value right in the controller before you return from the controller method. An example line might be as follows:

```
@GetMapping
public String getSomething(Model model) {
    if (sortDir == null) { sortDir = "asc" };
    model.addAttribute("sortDir", sortDir);
    return "someView";
}
```